# LightTable: How to format code?

Tags: lighttable

How do you format code in the LightTable IDE? I'm talking about the equivalent of *Ctrl + Shift + F* in Eclipse.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this by holding *CTRL + SPACE* and then searching for *"Smart Indent"*.

Comment: Cool, I did not know about smart indent

Comment: You have to select the text you want to format first.

Answer (score 0):

Light table does not have all the features of a full IDE yet, the main feature it has is live editing